# Convert custom type into string

Tags: string, clojurescript

Given a custom datatype in Clojurescript:

```
(deftype Foo [bar])
```

I would like to be able to convert this type into a string using the `str` macro. The result of `(str (->Foo "bar"))` is always `"[object Object]"`. Browsing through various docs and sources I found the `IPrintWithWriter` protocol that allows me to define a custom string representation. So the following extension is very close to what I'm looking for:

```
(extend-type Foo
  IPrintWithWriter
  (-pr-writer [this writer _] (-write writer (str "test:" (.-bar this)))))
```

Indeed, when using `(pr-str (->Foo "bla"))` the return value is indeed the string `"test:bla"`. However, the return value of `str` stays `"[object Object]"`.

How can I supply a custom string representation of `Foo` for `str` instead of for `pr-str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClojureScript's [`str`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/str) uses `Object.toString` method of the object passed as its argument:

> `(str x) returns x.toString()`

You can override this method for your `Foo` type:

```
(deftype Foo [bar]
  Object
  (toString [this]
    (str "Test: " bar)))
;; => cljs.user/Foo

(str (->Foo "x"))
;; => "Test: x"
```

Comment: Note: To cover all cases, you actually need to apply *both* the `Object.toString` *and* the `IPrintWithWriter.-pr-writer` approach. This means you'll see the correct string for `(str x)` and `(str [x])`.